# Answers requiring opinioins vs. requests for ideas

Tags: discussion

This question [One day projects for wood working fundamentals](https://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/3361/what-are-good-one-day-projects-for-wood-working-fundamentals) was put on hold for being opinion based. I understand questions that ask what is the best way to do something as of that type.  But this question appears to be looking for good ideas, not an arbitrary best one.  I think that a question asking for input as a positive for the site and a good habit for anyone growing their woodworking skills. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

It was a very broad question and needed more focus.  There are thousands of projects that can meet the requirements for that question and all can be 'correct'.  These are not good questions for the SE network questions.

Narrowing it down to wanting to use a specific tool, or a specific technique would bring it back on topic.  Closing and putting questions on hold give the OP a chance to better the question before a bunch of answers show up.  Because rewriting the question can invalidate them.

Comment: I understand, Thanks

Comment: Narrowing it down to a specific tool or technique *might* be a good first step towards bringing it on topic. E.g. "What are good one day projects for woodworking fundamentals that use a table saw" isn't much better.

Comment: @JasonC right, that was the minimum